# How to change thumb and track of scrollbar in scroll pane component? (Action Script 3) as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have added a scroll pane component to stage in Flash pro cs6. Need to use a different thumb and track for the scroll bar. What should I do to add a custom thumb and track to the existing scroll pane component?

Comment: ...you can double-click the component and edit the MovieClips...

Comment: Thank you :) Now I'm able to edit the track color of default scrollbar object, still couldn't edit the complete skin including thumb and arrow colour.

Comment: @ManofSnow Sorry, failed to notice hidden and locked layers. It working perfect. Thought it as complicated but, all I have to do is a double-click :) Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-click the **ScrollPane** to edit it.